# auto increment custom ID in database table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a EMPLOYEE table with EMP_ID,EMP_NAME,EMP_ADDRESS.  EMP_ID should have the following format.

```
EMP001
EMP002
EMP003
......
```

I also need to use EMP_ID as the primary key and should be auto generated is it possible?

Comment: How many employees do you anticipate there will be? more than 999?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an IDENTITY and a computed column?

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
     RealID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
     EMP_NAME ...
     ...
     /*gives 000-999. Change the RIGHT as needed to give more*/
     EMP_ID AS 'EMP' + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(RealID as varchar(10)), 3)

     CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EMP_ID)
     )
```

You can change the RIGHT to cover as many digits as needed, or you may not want leading zeroes:

```
     EMP_ID AS 'EMP' + CAST(RealID as varchar(10))
```